# Oracle JDBC thin client 64 bit

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'd like to know if there is a specific driver for 64-bit systems. I have a 64-bit tomcat server and I need to install the oracle driver. I did not see anything specific in the Oracle download page.

Comment: The thin driver is 100% Java and needs no external libraries. Therefor it can run on any JVM be it 32bit or 64bit. So the answer is: no you don't need a different driver for a 64bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
Does this help?

Comment: You don't need the instant client when using the JDBC thin driver.